# How to hide and show div border line in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css

I have a div element:

```
<div id="fruit-part">
      <input type="radio" name="fruits" value="apple">Apple
      <input type="radio" name="fruits" value="orange">Orange
</div>
```

My css to define the div border color

```
#fruit-part {
     border: 1px solid #cc3;
}
```

By using jQuery: `$('#fruit-part').hide()` and `$('#fruit-part').show()` I can easily **hide** and **show** the content inside the `div`, BUT not the div border line.

As you saw above, my `div` has a border line with color "#cc3", I am wondering, how to use jQuery to also hide and show the div border line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your CSS properties to a class, and then add/remove that class from `fruit-part`.

```
.bordered {
    border: 1px solid #cc3;
}

#fruit-part {}
```

```
$('#fruit-part').addClass('bordered');
$('#fruit-part').removeClass('bordered');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `css` method of JQuery:

```
$("#fruit-part").css("border", "");
```

Comment: Yes, I used, My question is actually on what value should be there? I tried 'none', it hide the border line, but how to show it then? I tried 'solid #cc3' , but it shows the border line with black color

Comment: Use `$("fruit-part").css("border", "1px solid #cc3");` to show the border again. If you don't like the empty string to hide the border, use `"0 none #fff"`;

Comment: I used, "1px solid #cc3" on firefox, I got black border line

Comment: You should use `"1px solid #ccs"` if you want to SHOW the border. To completely hide the border, use `"0px none #fff"`. To keep the border, but not show it, use `"1px solid #fff"` (assuming your background color to be `#fff`).

Answer (score 2):

```
/* CSS */
.noborder { border: 0; }
//Hide border
$('#fruit-part').addClass('noborder');
//Show border
$('#fruit-part').removeClass('noborder');
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#fruit-part').css('border', '');` and `$('#fruit-part').css('border', '1px solid #cc3');`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `$('#fruit-part').toggle();` to show and hide the whole div.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hNxQ5/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('#fruit-part').toggle();
});
```

```css
#fruit-part {
  border: 1px solid #cc3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fruit-part">
  <input type="radio" name="fruits" value="Mango">Mango
  <input type="radio" name="fruits" value="pineapple">Pineapple
</div>

<a href="#">Toggle visibilty</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.